# Can I change my character's race/name after the start?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was asked what my race was, and I chose...but then I managed to exit without setting a name, gender...anything else.  So now I'm a dude called "Prisoner".  I'd hate to play the whole game with such a lame name.  Am I going to be given an opportunity, like in Oblivion, to change these things again at some point, or do I need to start over, or...?

Comment: Me too. I hate being called prisoner. I managed to pick a race and a sex, even change my features, but I am known as prisioner.

Comment: Does typing `player.SetActorFullName "Something More Awesome"` in the console work? (That's how to change your name in Oblivion. I'd test it myself by I'm away from my Skyrim install.)

Comment: Sadly, the "fix" for me (since I am on an Xbox, and therefore don't have a console) was to just start the game over.

Comment: yep, sounds like since the console isn't available on the console versions (heh heh) we're out of luck on PS3 and xbox.  The game does make an autosave right when the guard calls you off the wagon, skipping almost five minutes of intro, but that's little consolation to having to restart

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to change your character's details after the initial setup is through the [console](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), which is only available on the PC version.

You can use the /showracemenu command to change the details. See [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29) for a listing of all console commands.

Comment: Note that the showracemenu is known to mess up your stats if you change your race, though only doing cosmetic changes seems fine.

Comment: Yes, **don't even scroll** between races, that **will** mess up your stats. Just choose the same race, then cosmetic changes (including sex and name) can be changed freely.

Comment: What about `player.setrace`?  Is that safe?

Answer (score 2):

I have played skyrim and so far I haven't had the option to change my name or race. I don't think there will be a way... but we will see.

Answer (score 2):

In the PC version, /showracemenu worked fine for me, and I successfully changed my appearance (eye-color, mainly), without affecting my skills, level, or anything like that (I recall in Oblivion there was a fairly convoluted way to do it -- this is much easier).  I've heard changing your race is a bad idea though.

I've heard there's a converter to change your savegame from XBox 360 to PC and back.  If you can find one of those, and have a friend (or know someone online) with the PC version, you could give them the savegame, run the console command, adjust your name, then convert it back to XBox 360.

Seeing as it's a single-player game, I really don't see any tos issues with a converter (you can supposedly do this to redo your perks, or give yourself a billion health, etc., as well).  However, having never seen or used it, I've no idea if it might corrupt your savegame later.

Another possibility might be to hex-edit the data on the XBox 360 version of the savefile from your computer.  I can't find my character name this way, but someone better at that sort of thing might be able to find it (editing the name on the first line of the file just changes the text displayed on the save/load screes, not the name of the player container).  Your best luck in that case would be to make the new name eight characters long, or there might be formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

/showracemenu works, HOWEVER! Your hands will be bound and I have not figured out how to remove that via the console yet. No doubt it is some simple console command to remove the bound hands affliction. Or just draw your weapon or magic to remove the binded hands effect.

Comment: Actually, it's probably a complicated console command to trigger the right part of the tutorial dungeon quest script.

Comment: actually, just hit R and bound hands are gone, bam